# Split single column with irregular sampling into multiple columns with same timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transformation, resampling

I have an export from a system which I cannot change and I need to modify my data for analysis. My dataframe has following format:

```
Timestamp  |  Name | Value
===========================
'14:00:00' | Var A | 0
'14:00:01' | Var A | 1
'14:00:02' | Var A | 2
...
'15:00:00' | Var A | 3600
'14:00:00' | Var B | 0
'14:10:00' | Var B | 600
..
'15:00:00' | Var B | 3600
'14:00:00' | Var C | 1000
...
```

So it is basically a union of logs of multiple variables with each having a different sampling frequency. What I need is to have a single sampling frequency (e.g 1 second) and each variable in independent column. So what I need to achieve is this:

```
Timestamp  |Var A  | Var B| Var C|.....
'14:00:01' | 0     | 0    | 1000 | ...
'14:00:02' | 1     | 1    |  ... |
'14:00:03' | 2     | 2    |      |
    ...    | ...   | ...  |      |
'15:00:00' | 3600  | 3600 |      |
```

Note that B originally had period of readings 10 minutes, but now has 1 second and the values are interpolated. I'm fairly new to pandas, so any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#if neccessary
#df['Timestamp']= df['Timestamp'].apply(eval)
new_df = (df.assign(Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].astype(str)))
            .pivot(*df)
            .asfreq('s')
            .reset_index()
            .assign(Timestamp = lambda x: x['Timestamp'].dt.time)
            .interpolate()
            .rename_axis(columns = None)
         )
print(new_df)

     Timestamp   Var A   Var B   Var C
0     14:00:00     0.0     0.0  1000.0
1     14:00:01     1.0     1.0  1000.0
2     14:00:02     2.0     2.0  1000.0
3     14:00:03     3.0     3.0  1000.0
4     14:00:04     4.0     4.0  1000.0
...        ...     ...     ...     ...
3596  14:59:56  3596.0  3596.0  1000.0
3597  14:59:57  3597.0  3597.0  1000.0
3598  14:59:58  3598.0  3598.0  1000.0
3599  14:59:59  3599.0  3599.0  1000.0
3600  15:00:00  3600.0  3600.0  1000.0

[3601 rows x 4 columns]
```